# Github webhook unable to connect to server with Spinnaker

Tags: google-app-engine, github, spinnaker

I'm following a spinnaker codelab https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/tutorials/codelabs/appengine-source-to-prod/ and having troubles with the github webhook integration.

From github I get a message that says `couldn't connect to server`

My github setup is:

```
Payload Url - http://<my-external-ip>:8089/webhooks/git/github
Content Type - application/json
Which events to trigger - just the push event
Active - true
```

My GCP Firewall rule is set to:

```
Priority - 1000
Direction - Ingress
Action on match - Allow
Target tags - allow-github-webhook
Source filters (IP Ranges) - 192.30.252.0/22   185.199.108.0/22
Protocols and ports - tcp:8089
```

And I've made sure my Spinnaker VM has the `network tags: allow-github-webhook`

I'm using Spinnaker v. 1.0.1

Is there anything I'm missing or any logs I might be able to check to see if an error is occurring anywhere? Or anything else you'd suggest to try to debug why the webhook isn't successful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from a contributor on the spinnaker project: https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker.github.io/issues/234

It was suggested to run the following inside the spinnaker machine and that made the webhook work:

```
echo "host: 0.0.0.0" | tee ~/.hal/default/service-settings/echo.yml
sudo hal deploy apply
```